# How to pass arguments in Matlab to Word

Tags: matlab, ms-word, activex

I'm working on an app which creates a data sheet based on a variety of measurements. I have made a template in word and I would like to print the first page only in .png format by calling Word as an activex application in Matlab.

I have created a class (`cWord`) that allows me to communicate with Word as an activex element. It allows me to modify everything in the document and looks something like this:

```
pth = './data/template.docx'
wrd = cWord(pth)
```

The class contains a handle to the document (`wordHandle`) and to the word application itself (`actxWord`). It also contains a lot of other functionality, however, that is not relevant for this question.

I am able to call the `PrintOut` function in Word as follows:

```
wrd.actxWord.PrintOut
```

Which works like a charm, except, I can not figure out how to pass the arguments I want to use.

In VBA it would look something like this:

```
Application.PrintOut Pages:=1
```

So what I'm basically asking is: What is the syntax for passing the `Pages` argument in the `PrintOut` function when using activeX in Matlab?

Comment: Have you try a `methods(yourobject,'-full');` to check which methods are available and which kind of variable are supported by those methods ?

Comment: @obchardon Yup. It returns a heap of methods, one of which is `PrintOut(handle, Variant(Optional))`. Is there a similar way to get more information about the function in question?

Comment: not really helpfull indeed. So I guess that you can use the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.printout) from microsoft. In matlab it would looks like `wrd.actxWord.PrintOut('False','False',3,'path/mydoc.docx',1,1)` according to the doc.